# Compond query with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform a search with the intended criteria being (`activationDate` in range `1598889600` to `1602051579`) or `someFlag`=`true`.

Below is the query I tried, but it does not yield any records with `someFlag`=`true` (even with a big size, e.g. 5000). My Elasticsearch does have a lot of records with `someFlag`=`true`.

There are about 3000 total documents and this query returns around 280 documents.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "activationDate": {
              "gte": 1598889600
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "activationDate": {
              "lte": 1602051579
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "someFlag": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 1,
  "size": 1000
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "activationDate": {
                    "gte": 1598889600,
                    "lte": 1602051579
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "someFlag": true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In theory this should do the same:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "activationDate": {
              "gte": 1598889600,
              "lte": 1602051579
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "someFlag": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However the first query I've given wraps bool clause within a filter context (so that it does not need to score and query becomes cacheable).

Your bool query might have not worked because you were using `match` query, not `term`. `match` is normally used for text search only.

Comment: Thanks. If I replace `term` with `match` in your second query, that works too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the must with an should and set minimum_should_match=1 as is is an OR query and you are fine if just one of the ceiterias is met by any record. Next reduce the two range criterias to just one, where you combine gte and lte.

Comment: {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "activationDate": {
                            "gte": 1598889600,
                            "lte": 1602051579
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "someFlag": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "from": 1,
    "size": 1000
}

Like this? This works.